# Trying to access files from Win11 on dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, files

I was asked to clarify, so here goes.
I've got a dual boot Windows 11/Ubuntu Studio 21.10 machine. I'm running Ubuntu and try to connect to the Windows partition to access files. Using Dolphin I click on the Windows drive and I am prompted for a password. I guess Win 11 doesn't use passwords anymore, so I tried my sister's pin. Its her machine I am trying to remotely set up. I never had to provide credentials with my Win 10/Ubuntu machine.

Original write up below.

I was able to remotely help my sister dual boot windows 11 and Ubuntu Studio 21.10. The problem is that I can't access the files on Windows 11 from Ubuntu. I'm prompted for a password. It would be easy to play around with it an try harder to figure it out, if the computer wasn't 500 miles away. Perhaps I haven't used the right search terms, but I couldn't find the answer.

Comment: Turn off fast startup and try again.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1385253/edit) and explain how you are trying to "access the files on Windows 11 from Ubuntu"? Are you trying to mount the Windows NTFS partition in Ubuntu? Are you trying to use SAMBA to access a shared folder in Windows 11 from a another computer running Ubuntu?

Comment: Check if Windows 11 is using partition encryption such as Bitlocker.

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll try these things tomorrow when I remote into my sister's machine again.

I've edited the original question to hopefully add clarity

Comment: So is the partition encrypted?

Comment: I believe I'd in limbo.  You have to finish activating bitlocker to dea tivate it. In going to reinstall ubuntu for my sister. Grub didn't seen to get installed and the onetime bot menu option doesn't see the Ubuntu OS. Turns out you can install teamviewer while running a live usb, so I'll take care of the install myself this time.